# Searching a List<Class> in C#

Tags: c#, .net, search

fellows.

In my simple project, there is a class:

```
public class TheOnlyClass
{
 private string label,name,smth;
 private int number;
 ...
}
```

Then I have a List declared in my Program body.

```
private static List<TheOnlyClass> classDB;
```

Then I got a function InitFromFile(). Does exactly what it says. Parses text file line by line, splits it into 3 strings and 1 int.

Later I get input from user, stating a TheOnlyClass.label, .name, .smth and/or .number.

What should I use to find all the records that fit my terms? Also is there any general advice: should I use a separate container for results or should I just display them one by one as they are found? Or maybe an array of pointers?

If you feel I missed something, tell me so :)

Thanks in advance,

~~hlfrmn

EDIT:

By the way, is there something in C# so I can check, which of the class members user need search in and pass this into a function as 1011(specified everything except name), for example. Or 0100 (meaning, he only needs name search, doesnt care about other things).

Comment: See [List<T>.FindAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fh1w7y8z%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: [Question the first](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Question the second](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691131(v=vs.71).aspx)

[Question the third which follows](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)

Did you try anything before asking?

Comment: you can use the FindAll() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use LINQ.

```
List<TheOnlyClass> myClass = GetTheClassData();
var matches = from c in myClass where 
                   c.label == LabelValue || 
                   c.name == NameValue || 
                   c.smith == SmithValue ||
                   c.number == NumberValue
              select c;
```

Here are some great example LINQ queries:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

If you need "ANDs" replace || with &&

Comment: The link is awesome. For some reason, haven't found it yet. I just wish i had had it earlier, when I was dealing with some lame XML file.

Comment: Another great tool for LINQ in my toolbox is LINQpad.  It's great when your query isn't quite working right and you want to know why.  [link]http://www.linqpad.net

Comment: Are there any bad possible consequences of using LINQ with List<Actions> ? Just asking, how people actually dynamically choose a function to be executed without writing a lot of overloads.

Comment: Quick question, how do I know if matches yielded result? Can I do `matches.Count()`?